# Wpf Binding a TextBlock to App Property's member

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, global, textblock

In my WPF app, I want an object "CaseDetails" to be used globally i.e. by all windows & user controls. CaseDetails implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and has a property CaseName.

```
public class CaseDetails : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string caseName, path, outputPath, inputPath;

    public CaseDetails()
    {
    }

    public string CaseName
    {
        get { return caseName; }
        set
        {
            if (caseName != value)
            {
                caseName = value;
                SetPaths();
                OnPropertyChanged("CaseName");
            }
        }
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

In my App.xaml.cs, I created an object of CaseDetails

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private CaseDetails caseDetails;

    public CaseDetails CaseDetails
    {
        get { return this.caseDetails; }
        set { this.caseDetails = value; }
    }
```

In one of my user control code behind, I create object of CaseDetails and set in App class

```
(Application.Current as App).CaseDetails = caseDetails;
```

And the CaseDetails object of App class is updated.

In my MainWindow.xml, I have a TextBlock that is bind to CaseName property of CaseDetails. This Textblock doesn't update. The xml code is :

```
<TextBlock Name="caseNameTxt" Margin="0, 50, 0, 0" FontWeight="Black" TextAlignment="Left" Width="170" Text="{Binding Path=CaseDetails.CaseName, Source={x:Static Application.Current} }"/>
```

Why this TextBlock Text poperty is not getting updated ?? Where am I going wrong in Binding ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binding isn't updated because you are setting the `CaseDetails` property in your App class, which does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Either you also implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your App class, or you just set properties of the existing CaseDetails instance:

```
(Application.Current as App).CaseDetails.CaseName = caseDetails.CaseName;
...
```

The `CaseDetails` property might then be readonly:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private readonly CaseDetails caseDetails = new CaseDetails();

    public CaseDetails CaseDetails
    {
        get { return caseDetails; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried making CaseDetails as readonly and work that way, but it made no difference. Finally I tried implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in App class, and this did the binding updations. Thanks